# have difficulty vs have hard time vs have trouble vs struggle

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

**have difficulty/
have a hard time /

have trouble/ 
 struggle** + ing

Among the four expressions above, what are the most common expression in daily conversation when I simply want to say it was hard or tough to do something?
Are there any expressions that sound a little awkward in casual situations?

(ex- I **struggled/ had difficulty/ a hard time/ trouble** explaining the cultural difficulties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any of these phrases would sound awkward in conversation, but they might have slightly different connotations.

> I **have difficulty** doing the thing

**Having difficulty** may have more 'proper' connotation, and might sound more formal.

> I **have a hard time** doing the thing

**Having a hard time** sounds more informal, and is mostly synonymous with **having trouble** with something.

> I **struggle** with doing the thing

**Struggling** is a more formal way to say that you had trouble, but it usually implies that the struggle has lasted a long time with little gain. It is sometimes used with poetic undertones.